# htaccess showing main site instead of subfolder on multi-language site

Tags: .htaccess, multilingual

I am working on a website with multi-language support. The URLs are in the format:

```
https://example.com/gb/en/
https://example.com/fr/fr/
```

`gb` refers to the country, `en` refers to the language. The `.htaccess` file handles these variables and loads the language specific data from a file.

I am trying to duplicate this site in a subfolder, and have it working completely seperately to the original site.

```
https://example.com/promo/gb/en/
https://example.com/promo/fr/fr/
```

My `.htaccess` file looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

#force https 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteRule \.js$ /sprocketize.php [QSA,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^(admin) - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(app) - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(ws) - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(opia) - [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^promo-select(/)?$ /promo-select.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/$2 [R=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([a-z]{2})(?:/(.*)|)$ /$1/$3?lang=$2 [NC,QSA,PT]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})(?:/(.*)|)$ /$2?country=$1 [NC,QSA,PT]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ /$2?keyword=$1 [NC,QSA,PT]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[^./]+)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.php [NC,QSA]
```

I've tried changing

`RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ /$2?keyword=$1 [NC,QSA,PT]`

to

`RewriteRule ^promo/([^/]+)/(.*)$ /promo/$2?keyword=$1 [NC,QSA,PT]`

etc., but it's either loading the original site or showing a 'page not found' error. I've also tried adding `RewriteBase /promo` but it just loaded the main site. I suspect I'm doing something obvious/stupid wrong. Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I should have said, the files in the subfolder are the same as the root folder, including the `.htaccess` file. There are 2 `.htaccess` files, 1 in the root, 1 in the subfolder. I've been editing the one in the subfolder.

Comment: I've currently got it working as http://promo.example.com/gb/en/ but this isn't ideal as it's not going through the SSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Important**
While working with .htaccess is usually important to clear browser cache after editing the file. I've had some problems with this

Have you tried to rewrite urls to your folder?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /promo/
```

Notice the trailing '/' and this, I think, should be on top

I use this and it works with my server...

Please try this and tell us what happens:
1. Change

```
RewriteRule ^promo-select(/)?$ /promo-select.php [L,NC]
```

to:

```
RewriteRule ^promo-select(/)?$ promo-select.php [L,NC]
```

If above don't work, try:
Change

```
RewriteRule ^promo-select(/)?$ /promo-select.php [L,NC]
```

to:

```
RewriteRule ^promo-select(/)?$ /promo/promo-select.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried adding this to the htaccess file in the subfolder, but it makes no difference. I should have said I have 2 htaccess files, 1 in the root and 1 in the subfolder. I want to keep the existing site up and running at it's current address, and add a duplicate site in the subfolder.

Comment: yes. that structure it's perfectly accepted. What's the output after placing those two lines, cleaning the cache and accessing an url?

Comment: With that in place, clearing cache and accessing it, it shows the home page of the root site. It seems to be ignoring the 'promo' part.

Comment: That was it :-) Keeping `RewriteBase /promo/` and removing the starting slash from `promo-select.php` has fixed it, thanks a lot.